# Google sheets - Sum of values in excel with condition

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, sumifs

Considering this scenario with an example I require

Excel function that provides a solution for the following problem

Column A and B have the following entries. D has the unique values of column A

```
    A    B    C    D    E
1   x   10         x    25
2   y   20         y    30
3   x   15
4   y   10
```

So the Output will be displayed on the Columns E
with the sum of the corresponding values in column B

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this in [google-sheets](/questions/tagged/google-sheets) or [excel](/questions/tagged/excel)

```
=sumifs(b:b, a:a, d1)
```

Answer (score 2):

One simple way to do things like aggregation on your Excel table is to use a pivot table.  Just add headers for the `A` and `B` columns, then highlight your data and insert a pivot table.  Here is a screen shot:

[image]

And here is a screen capture showing how I configured the pivot table:

[image]

Comment: Is there a more dynamic way? If I add more entries, it should automatically pick them up and add

Comment: If you're asking whether new `var` categories, and their sums, would automatically appear, then the answer is yes, they would.  If you have requirements other than this, then state them, and maybe I can update my answer.